# mounted function calling multiple times vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a mounted function in my vue.js page first time when my page loads this.editId variable contains value but second and third time also mounted function is automatically called which shows

> ```
> app.js:1088 GET http://localhost:8000/api/backend/bill/undefined 404 (Not Found)
> ```

but first time i'm getting the editId value in my console.

```
  export default {
      components: {
            Datepicker,datetime
        },
      async mounted(){
           const header = {
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.LoginUserData,
                };
            this.editId = this.$route.params.id;
             try{   
             console.log(this.editId);
             let response = await axios.get(`/api/backend/bill/${this.editId}` ,{headers: header});
             this.form = response.data;
             }catch(err){
              
             }
        },
```

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I want to make sure. Is your problem that that mounted call multiple time? Or the problem for the value of this.editId when you refresh the page for multipe time?